# Words Listed by Vowel Sound

Tags: vowels, phonetics, music, ipa

I'm working on a libretto for a vocal composition which makes use of vowel formants. It's important that all of the singers can produce exactly the same vowel sound, so I'm using IPA symbols.

I'm wondering if there is a resource available that lists words by their vowel sound. I've found a number of rhyming dictionaries, but I'm looking for something more technical. My main problem is that any slight variation in the pronunciation of a vowel totally changes the frequencies of the formants, so I really need something that will be as specific as possible.

Thanks.

—Lucas

Comment: What would you like your dictionary to do that rhyming dictionaries and, say, [Longman's pronunciation dictionary](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/dictionaries/lpd/index.html) can't provide? Can you give an example with actual words that shows rhyming dictionaries aren't enough?

Comment: If you need people to be producing very specific formants, you might not be able to give examples in terms of English words. The principle of allophony means that the slight variations in pronunciation that you say are unacceptable won't distinguish between different English words.

Comment: What's the point of your search? Do you have two words and you want to se if they rhyme  as close as possible? Then any dictionary with a pronunciation (IPA or whatever) will work. Do you have a single word and you want to easily find words that rhyme? Then a rhyming dictionary. If notm then what do you mean exactly by "lists words by their vowel sound"? Ordered lexicographically by _only_ the vowels, and _then_ by the  consonants (sounds weird)?

Comment: @sumelic: if the OP can't give examples, then how are we to deduce what he's asking?

Comment: @Peter Shor: Sorry for the confusion--my comment was addressed to the OP. I was trying to say that there's no way, using English words, to get any more fine-grained in vowel qualities than the usual phonemic inventory of English. So I think his project will not work.

Comment: @sumelic: actually, you can get more fine-grained. In American English as most of us speak it, the vowel of *bank* (and its rhymes) isn't quite the same as the vowel of *back* or *bat* (and their rhymes), even though they're the same phoneme.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I actually just thought about that example of allophony. But I'm still confused as to why OP can't just say "a as in back" if he has to differentiate the two...

Comment: @Peter The vowels in _back_ and _bat_ aren't the same either—and there's a ton of variation between speakers, even of the same dialect, between all three of them. One speaker's _bank_ a may be another's _bat_ a, etc.

Comment: The querant may be looking for a _rhyming dictionary._

Comment: What makes you think that all your singers will know how to interpret IPA spellings? And why do you think they would otherwise pronounce the same word differently? Perhaps the best route is to make sure all your singers are from the same city; who pronouncedmost of the phonemes the way you want them pronounced, then coach them on the ones they normally pronounce differently.

Comment: As I understand it, vowel pronunciations are much more dynamic than the layman would assume (as Peter Shor pointed out with the example of "bank" and "back.") The first thing that I am looking for, is a pronunciation guide that will give me this degree of specificity. I also understand that pronunciations vary widely based on region, so it would be ideal if this guide could serve as a sort of "Platonic ideal" of English pronunciation; something that I could base my composition around.

Comment: Of course, what would be most helpful of all is a resource ordered, as Mitch said, lexicographically by vowel first and consonant second.